# Firebase Messaging .onBeckgroundMessage with overriden didRecieveRemoteNotification in AppDelegate in Flutter app

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing an issue with implementing firebase messaging together with overriden function 'didRecieveRemoteNotification' in AppDelegate.

In my Flutter project, i have set up firebase and firebaseMessaging. I also set up FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage() to handle some actions when push notification is recieved with app on background/terminated. This is the initialization:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("---Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  configureGetIt();
  runApp(...)
}
```

This works correctly for android and iOS. But once i modify the AppDelegate.swift with overriden function didRecieveRemoteNotification like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        NSLog("---PN data: \(userInfo)")
    }
}
```

The defualt handling of PN's by firebase messaging package stops working on iOS (the onBackgroundMessage does not trigger anymore). I would like to ask, if anyone has any idea how to set up the overrident function in AppDelegate correctly to ensure that the firebase messaging package still handles the PN's correctly.

Any idea is much appreciated